# How do i over write a specific bit in a register? (assembly language)

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

say i have a register t0 0x0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0010 0001
and i want to turn all the 1 into 0. 
How do i do this one by one? (no use of move $t0,$0)

I am thinking about using sb(store byte).

Answer (score 1):

The expression (a & (-a)) equals to the least significant bit in a word.
e.g.

```
0xbcd0 = 1011 1100 1101 0000 =  48336  
         0100 0011 0011 0000 = -48336  
-------------------------------------
 AND =   0000 0000 0001 0000 <-- lsb set
```

In pseudo code:

```
while (-a & a) { a ^= (-a & a); }  // cache the common sub expression...
```

There are multiple methods that clear / set certain bits:

- xor: toggle a bit
- and: clear everything but a certain bit
- or:  sets a bit
- sub: clears a bit if it was set
- add: sets a bit if it was clear (otherwise produces a 'carry' that propagates left)
- andn: clears a bit
- `(1<<n)`, with 0<=n< (word size in bits) is used to convert bit position to bit masks
- `LSB_MASK=(1<<n)-1` is a bit mask that has all *n* rightmost (least significant bits set)
- `MSB_MASK=-1<<n` has (W-n) leftmost (most significant) bits set, when W=# of bits in word
- `(a + (a & LSB_MASK))` makes "room" for one bit to the left of LSB_MASK

Answer (score 0):

Dunno MIPS, but here's a way to clear bit by bit in pseudocode.  I assume registers work sanely, and shifts out of the left side just get thrown away.

```
mask = -2
Til param = 0:
    (clearing bits one at a time is stupid unless you care which ones are set)
    If (param AND mask) != param, do something

    param <== param AND mask
    Shift mask one bit left
```

Technically this will clear the low bit, then the low 2 bits, then the low 3...etc.  But this will be fine if you're dealing with registers.  (Once you've cleared a bit, it's not really like you can make it *more* zero.  :)  )

Answer (score -1):

```
[PUSH ax]
 MOV ax, $to
 AND ax, 0
 MOV $to, ax
[PULL ax]
```

having: `p & 0 = 0`, then:

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0010 0001 
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
 --------------------------------------- AND
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```